# Vim Automatic Line Wrapping in Markdown

Tags: vim, markdown

I have the following two lines in my `vimrc`:

```
set textwidth=80
set formatoptions-=t
```

This allows me to format my source such that there are line breaks after 80 characters using commands such as `gq`. This has been working fine for me.

However, when editing some markdown source (.md file), I notice that when I type an unordered list element of the form:

```
* My unordered list element
```

`vim` automatically wraps the line after 80 characters.

An easy workaround is to use the `+` symbol  instead of the asterisk, but I'm curious as to what may be the reason for the different behavior in this case.

Comment: Have you enabled a plugin for markdown? Since that could overwrite your defaults.

Comment: I'm using [ghmarkdown.vim](https://github.com/jtratner/vim-flavored-markdown)

Comment: Could you try if it still happens with that plugin disabled?

Comment: Mind my ignorance, it's not a plugin, it's a syntax file.

Comment: Regardless, the issue persists even with the plugin/syntax file removed.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely caused by the following two lines in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/markdown.vim`:

```
setlocal formatoptions+=tcqln
setlocal formatlistpat=^\\s*\\d\\+\\.\\s\\+\\\|^[-*+]\\s\\+
```

You can check with

```
:verbose setlocal formatoptions?
```

To undo the effects, put the corresponding `:setlocal` commands into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`.

Comment: Depends on what exact formatting you want, e.g. `setlocal formatoptions-=t` (undo the wrapping) or `setlocal formatoptions+=tcqln` (undo every ftplugin format setting).

Answer (score 2):

Try running vim without any plugins or configuration

```
vim -u NONE test.md
set textwidth=80
set formatoptions-=t
```

If you do this then the text will not wrap automatically which tells us that it must either be a plugin or something in your `.vimrc` file.

You can find out what plugins have been sourced using `:scriptnames`.

I would disable all plugins then re-enable them one by one till the problem reappears.